# Как объявить несколько переменных за раз?

Tags: javascript

```
var i, sum = 5;
console.log(i); // undefined
console.log(sum); // 5
```

Почему не обе переменные равны 5, в JS же вроде была такая возможность, как ей правильно воспользоваться?

Comment: _Почему не обе переменные равны 5_ - потому что значение присваивается только `sum`.

Comment: Перечисление переменных через запятую – только для того чтобы каждый раз не писать `var`

Comment: @marrk2 ты наверное спутал `var i, sum = 5;` с `var i = sum = 5;`

Comment: Можно инициализировать каждую переменную при создании используя один **var**.

`var i = 5, sum = 5;
console.log(i);
console.log(sum);`

Comment: @Grundy, будь другом, посмотри мой последний ответ, хочу знать твое мнение, я вроде бы ответил, но криво...  посмотри, укажи на  ошибки.. я 
 не ради балов отвечал, а для себя.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ай-ай-ай) переменная sum проходит без var - не надо так)

Comment: @vp_arth, на верхнем уровне и так сойдет :)

Comment: @vp_arth точно? но звиняйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В  вашем случае переменой **i** не присвоено значение.

Если вы хотите разным переменным задать одно значение  можете сделать например вот так:

> Код JavaScript:

```
  var a = 'Переменная А', b = c = d = "5";

  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
  console.log(d);
```

> Результат данного кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стоит добавить, что в примере переменные `c` и `d` утекут в глобальную область видимости.

Answer (score 1):

```
var i=5, sum=5;
```

Наверное так нужно.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/211228)

Comment: @Anatol чего, по вашему, не хватает в этом ответе для решения?

Comment: @NickVolynkin предположение не может быть ответом по определению. Если бы было что-то ещё, кроме предположения, то было бы ответом

Comment: @Anatol по определению ответа или предположения? Это честная попытка ответа. Даже если она ошибочна, это всё равно ответ. Но похоже, что ошибки нет, ответ верный.

Comment: @NickVolynkin верность/неверность ответа не является критерием, верно? *не следует использовать сигнал тревоги для неточных или не верных ответов* говорит о том, что мы не должны вникать в суть ответа. Но тут ситуация такова, что человек сделал предположение и неважно, верно оно оказалось или нет. Посыл такой: хочешь дать ответ - убедись в его верности, а потом отвечай. А для предположений место в комментариях

Answer (score -1):

```js
var i = sum = 5
let j = day = 3
const x = y = z = 0
console.log(i, sum)
console.log(j, day)
console.log(x,y,z)
```

Comment: стоит добавить описание  к коду, а так же пояснение почему в примере `y` и `z` **не** будут константами